# Nuxt Axios Module error handling and http status code

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm using axios to call the backend of my nuxt application. When an error happens on that backend call I learned I can handle it with the `.onError()` method of axios.

Nearly everything I find around docs and issues through google suggests to do a redirect to some /404 error page or something. Unfortunately this still returns an http 200 status code which I think isn't appropriate. I'd prefer to fire the same 404 error (and also display the same error page) when a 404 happens on the backend than is fired and shown to the user with missing pages on Nuxt (display handled through layouts/error.vue).

I thought the error() function from the context should do the trick but I can't seem to get this working.

```
export default function ({ $axios, error }) {
  $axios.onError(axioserror => {
    const code = parseInt(axioserror.response && axioserror.response.status)
    error(code)
  })
}
```

Comment: As i read in docs you need to call error a bid differently. error({ statusCode: code})

Comment: @Helmi did you find anything?